# c++ directory Iterator exception on VS2019- have changed language setting, what else to try, has it changed for 2019?

Tags: c++, iterator, boost-filesystem

I have moved to vs2019 from 2017 now and it has come with a couple of minor yet annoying challenges...

one of them is this piece of code I have developed for iterating through a directory and pushing the file paths into an array.

I have updated the language setting to the latest draft on the property pages that let me remove the:: experimental in the namespace.

The code builds but when debugging and stepping through it throws an exception when the iterator tries to initialize to the directory path.

what am I missing as it was working ok a couple of days ago on vs2017..

[image: screenshot!]

I have checked the library and I think I am providing what it is asking for?

[image: library]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below on you machine and feedback (via comment), if it worked?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main() {

    // The start path
    const fs::path startPath{ "C:\\temp\\" };

    std::vector<std::string> files{};

    // Get all path names as string
    std::transform(fs::directory_iterator(startPath), {}, std::back_inserter(files), [](const fs::directory_entry& de) { return de.path().string(); });

    // Output all files
    std::copy(files.begin(), files.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

Because this works on my machine with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.5.2

Comment: Hi, that code works as intended yes. I think my problem may be syntax related, you set your iterator up with {} let me try that and see if it works again.